# If modal is active/shown add modal-open not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question is asked a lot but all the answers I've found all have the same answer which is great for most but it isn't working with my code,

This is the Javascript to open my modals

```
$(".button-b, .item, .item2, .button-a, .port_item").on("click", function() {
    var modal = $(this).data("modal");
    $(modal).show();
});

$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
    var className = e.target.className;
    if(className === "modal" || className === "closex"){
      $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
    }
});
```

I could just add `$("html","body").addClass("modal-open");` to `.button-a, .button-b").on("click", function() {` and `$("html","body").removeClass("modal-open");` to `$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {` but because I've linked `.button-b. .button-a` any button that uses those styles also adds `.modal-open` to the body which means when someone clicks a button that isn't opening a modal the screen freezes and you can't scroll,

I tried to come up with something to work around it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modal = $(this).data("modal");
    if (modal = show) {
    $("html","body").addClass("modal-open");
  } else {
    $("html","body").removeClass("modal-open")
  }
});
```

But I have absolutely no clue what I'm doing in javascript so it doesn't work - what I want it do is when the modal is active/shown to add `.modal-open` to the body, so that it's not adding `.modal-open` when any buttons with `.button-b, .button-a` stylings are clicked but only if the modal is shown, I'm guessing I need an event listener? any help would be great.

Comment: Can you include your html code, or attach a fiddle with your entire code so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Your code layout was confusing, have edited to make clear that they're two separate handlers

Comment: Cleaned the wording so new readers can understand the issue easier, knew I needed an if statement just didn't know how to add it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the following is incorrect...

```
$("html","body").addClass("modal-open");
```

The correct format is to list the selectors in the same string...

```
$("html, body").addClass("modal-open");
```

If I understand your issue correctly, the problem is that you're doing a hide on `$(modal)` independent of whether there is a result from `$(this).data("modal")`... and therefore adding the `addClass` within the same function results in no modal being shown, but the body being unusable.

So I believe this is more along the lines of what you want...

```
$(".button-b, .item, .item2, .button-a, .port_item").on("click", function() {
  var modal = $(this).data("modal");
  if (modal) {
    $(modal).show();
    $("html, body").addClass("modal-open");
  }
});

$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
  var className = e.target.className;
  if(className === "modal" || className === "closex"){
    $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
    $("html, body").removeClass("modal-open");
  }
});
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, added the .removeClass just below $(".modal").on("click", function(e) { too so that it removes .modal-open when I click the modal itself too, thanks man this is exactly what I wanted, do you know any good resources to learn javascript in an easy to understand way? currently just doing it by combining other pieces of code till I have something that works or having to ask for help

Comment: @JTR - sorry, I don't know any specific resources for learning javascript other than asking on Stackoverflow (I know it makes me sound flippant, but I've been doing JS for quite a number of years).  Glad I could help with this issue though, and I hope you're successful in the rest of your project :-)